# Using Higher Order Functions in Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, function

I'm trying to learn Ruby right now after learning Python and I'm having trouble translating this code to Ruby:

```
def compose1(f, g):
    """Return a function h, such that h(x) = f(g(x))."""
    def h(x):
        return f(g(x))
return h
```

Do I have to translate this using blocks? Or is there a similar syntax in Ruby?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  A word of caution, "Translate this code from language X to language Y" are usually unpopular around here.  Yours is a bit better than usual as it seems like you've dug around a little and have some idea what you're doing: "Do I have to translate this using blocks?".  That said, I hope somebody that knows ruby comes along and gives you a good answer -- I wouldn't mind knowing the answer to this one :-)

Comment: I'm in the midst of learning Python myself, so I'm going to shy away from posting a code solution to this.  But I highly recommend this reference guide when trying to translate code between Python/Ruby/Perl/PHP (has been very useful for me in translating Perl->Python): http://hyperpolyglot.org/scripting

Comment: Oh, my bad. I definitely did not know that translation questions are looked down upon. I was just wondering if there is similar syntax in Python since all my Google results were referring to blocks..but I'll keep that in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say `f` and `g` are the following methods:

```
def f(x)
  x + 2
end

def g(x)
  x + 3
end
```

We can define `compose1` as:

```
def compose1(f,g)
  lambda { |x| send(f, send(g, x) ) }
end
```

For this to work, we need to define h as:

`h = compose1(:f, :g)`

You will need to pass the method names as a string / symbol for `send` to work. Then, you can do

`h.call 3 # => 8`. More info can be found [here](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/54433)

Comment: I think this answer is more clear but Zach Kemp's is prettier.

Comment: Zach's is nice, but this allows you to use existing methods without making changes to them, which definitely has its benefits.

Comment: `f` and `g` aren't functions. They are methods. The two are *fundamentally* different.

Comment: Updated it to say method instead of function.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this with lambdas in Ruby (I'm using the 1.9 stabby-lambda here):

```
compose = ->(f,g) { 
  ->(x){ f.(g.(x)) }  
}
```

So `compose` is a function that returns another function, as in your example:

```
f = ->(x) { x + 1 }
g = ->(x) { x * 3 }

h = compose.(f,g)
h.(5) #=> 16
```

Note that functional programming is not really Ruby's strong suit - it can be done but it looks a bit messy in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

use lambdas

```
def compose1(f,g)
  return lambda{ |x| f.call(g.call(x)) }
end
```

Exemple of running

```
compose1(lambda{|a| a + 1}, lambda{|b| b + 1}).call(1)
```

Comment: Procs and lambdas are a different things (although similar).  You wrote about procs but used lambdas.